# Need to use jndi datasource defined in weblogic from a no context application

Tags: java, weblogic, datasource, jndi

I need to get programmatic the weblogic datasource (JNDI) for my application, I have my own Spring placeholder and at this point there is no applicationcontext created I can't get the datasource from context.

How can I get the datasource from weblogic programmatic?

Comment: Is your application running inside of Weblogic?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jdbc/programming.html Check the `Obtaining a Client Connection Using a DataSource` section

Comment: I found the way to obtain the datasource jndi from the server.

Properties p=new Properties();           p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://" + this.propertiesCompleto.getProperty("VAR.SERVERAPP.NAME") + ":" + this.propertiesCompleto.getProperty("VAR.SERVERAPP.PORT"));
InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext(p);
           ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup(this.propertiesCompleto.getProperty("database.jndiDataSource"));

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Java code,

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable(); 
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://localhost:7004,localhost:7005"); //cluster URL, if datasource deployed on cluster 
try{
    envContext = new InitialContext(ht);   // InitialContext();  
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/MyDataSource"); //if using Weblogic 12c, then remove `jdbc/` and just give the name of DataSource
    con = ds.getConnection();
    //.. use connection
    con.close();
}
catch(SQLException e)           
{e.printStackTrace();}
```

and update your web.xml file with `resource-ref`

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>MyDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```